# How to read raw input in cpp

Tags: c++, string, input, stream, cin

Imagine I want to copy-paste some text in stdin and I want to read it entirely in cpp (including whitespace). How can I do it? If I use cin, it reads tokens delimited by whitespace. If I do:

```
string text
string s;
while(cin>>s){
    text += s;
}
```

Then it gets indistinguishable whether it was space(" ") or newline("\n") between tokens.
Question is, how can I read the whole string.

Comment: `cin.read()` maybe?

Comment: If you just dump random text into stdin then you're not going to be able to detect when that text dump ends unless you have a well defined end market (like `'\n'`) or you trigger EOF (using something like `Ctrl-D` sequence). But you can just read whatever was dumped "line by line" (std::getline) or one char at a time `get()`?

Comment: @Galik How to mark '\n' as the only end character and not space? that might help.

Comment: @GeorgeTsertsvadze If you use `std::getline` it will read everything up to the end of line (or end of file) *including spaces*.

Comment: It depends on how you are planning on processing the data in your application. If you could provide more information it would be easier to suggest something specific.

Comment: @Galik can you give more specific example?

Comment: `std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);` // use line here

Comment: @Galik actually, I am just solving some algorithmic problem where input is just a big string (containing newlines and spaces) and I just have to read it, store in one string and then do the algorithm.

Comment: Then I don't think you can detect the end of the data dump unless you manually trigger end of file which will close `std::cin` and it will not receive new input (one time event).

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that is quick to code, use [`std::istream::getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

```
std::string text;
char c;
while ( std::cin.getc(c) )
{
   text.push_back(c);
}
```

If you expect the content of stdin to be large, this will be a performance problem. You should consider using [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) for such use cases.

Answer (score 0):

To make the result of the provided while loop approach distinguishable, I had to read it with `readline()` like this:

```
string text
string s;
while(readline(cin,s)){
    text += s + "\n";
}
```

This way, it's guaranteed that readline will read the whole line (with spaces) and the given tokens will be only delimited by "\n" (which can be added manually).

Answer (score 0):

From cplusplusreference.com:

> As an object of class istream, characters can be retrieved either as
>   formatted data using the extraction operator (operator>>) or as
>   unformatted data, using member functions such as read.

[cin - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/?kw=cin)

I get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char c;
    string text;

    while (!cin.read(&c, 1).eof())
        s += c;

    cout << "string was " << s << endl;
}
```

On Windows, end it with a <Ctrl-Z> on a line by itself, followed by <Enter>.  I tested it, and it does indeed include the end of line characters.